# How do I use field.get(obj) on a List field?

Tags: java, list, get, field

I want to get a private List field from a class, but I don't know what argument to give to field.get to successfully get the List from the class. My current code produces a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

```
Field field = Minecraft.class.getDeclaredField("defaultResourcePacks");
field.setAccessible(true);

List<IResourcePack> changedList = new ArrayList<IResourcePack>();

List<IResourcePack> list = (List<IResourcePack>) field.get(changedList);
```

Comment: Is your field static? Otherwise you need an actual object of the Minecraft class in order access it. Besides: is this for education purposes; or why do you turn to reflection to manipulate your objects?

Comment: The field is not static. This list stores all the textures for Minecraft, and the only way to load textures from an external source is to reflect this list and add to it.

Comment: Still, using reflection to something like this should be the last resort. Maybe the creators of that class did not want you to add textures?! The next time they change something, your code will break. Why don't you try to get into contact with them; and ask how to use their objects; or to provide an interface to do what you need?!

Comment: The creators of Minecraft itself had never meant for textures to be added this way, as they never intended to allow modding support. However, I could ask the creators of Minecraft Forge, the modding API that I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example:

```
List<IResourcePack> changedList = new ArrayList<IResourcePack>();
List<IResourcePack> list = (List<IResourcePack>) field.get(changedList);
```

You are using `get()` the wrong way. The expected argument must be an Object of class Minecraft; and `get` pulls the content of the field that you identified earlier on. In other words: you do not need an input parameter "changedList"; you need one that is a Minecraft object.

Comment: I will in 4 minutes, it won't let me yet

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `get(objOfMinecraft)`

Comment: Thanks Chen for correcting formatting, ashjack may be now it works for you